# Meteor progressbar for template subscriptions with actual progress

Tags: meteor

Is there a package for subscription progress for template subscriptions?

I have always used:
multiply:iron-router-progress

but I now switched to template subscriptions:

```
Template.templatename.onCreated(function() {
    var self = this;
    self.autorun(function(){
        self.subscribe("subname");
    });
});
```

which are not compatible with above progress package.
I now tried settinghead:auto-nprogress, but it seems to simply display an arbitrary loading bar with a statically defined timed progress. It is not actually showing the progress based on the subscription status (e.g. 120/1000 documents loaded).

Does anybody know a package that supports this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the implementation in the package you mention (https://github.com/Multiply/iron-router-progress/blob/master/progress.coffee), it is literally using random numbers to move the progress bar forward.  Looking at docs.meteor.com, I don't see any hooks in subscriptions that would allow you to do a meaningful progress bar tied to progress.

Instead, use `Template.subscriptionsReady` to either load your content or a loading spinner/etc.